# Autocomplete doesn't fill the data retrieved from Spring Boot API service

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-material

I'm trying to do an async searcher of teachers and I don't know what's happening. I'm using an autocomplete from Material Angular.

The thing is that I receive the data but I can't see the results in the autocomplete component.

This is my service:

```js
    export class PersonaService {

    private PERSONA_URL = 'list/buscarPersona'

    public items: Array<object>;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient) { }

    search(searchTerm: string): any {
        const url = this.PERSONA_URL;
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('texto', searchTerm);

        return this.http.get(url, {params: params})
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    };
    }
```

This is my component

```js
    public myControl = new FormControl();
    public filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;


    constructor(
        public personaService: PersonaService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.map(q => this.buscarPersona(q));
    }

    buscarPersona(searchTerm: any): any {
        this.personaService.search(searchTerm);
    }
```

And this is the html:

```html
    <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar persona" aria-label="Search" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value]="option">
                {{option}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

As I said, I see the objects in console but I can't see them in the autocomplete component.

What can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I feel that your HTTP request is not properly connected to the mat-autocomplete by Angular Material.

First, I'd check the search() function inside your service:

```js
search(searchTerm: string): any {
    const url = this.PERSONA_URL;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('texto', searchTerm);

    return this.http.get(url, {params: params})
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
};
```

You are subscribing to the http call to print the response. However, you are also returning that subscription. What you should do instead is remove the subscribe() and return this.http.get(url, {params: params}). You can add the return type to the function to be Observable.

See my suggestion here:

```js
search(searchTerm: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.PERSONA_URL;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('texto', searchTerm);

    return this.http.get(url, {params: params})
};
```

Then inside your component I think you need to use subscribe() instead of map() on the valueChanges and call the service directly like so:

```js
public myControl = new FormControl();
public filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;


constructor(
    public personaService: PersonaService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(q => this.personaService.search(searchTerm));
}
```

Now this will not work right away (and it wrong in other ways. I wanted to make step by step progression here ;-). The problem is that **this.myControl.valueChanges** is an observable and the call to **this.personaService.search(searchTerm)** *is another Observable nested in the first one*. This is called higher order Observable and you need to make sure to take the inner out of the outer:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        switchMap(searchTerm => this.personaService.search(searchTerm))
    ).subscribe(response => this.filteredOptions = response)
}
```

Three things happened here:

1. Instead of assigning whatever comes back from the method call to this.filteredOptions, we are doing this later within a subscribe block.
2. Using the RxJS pipe method allows to specify operators on the Observable. Here, we are using the switchMap which allows us to call the service that returns an Observable and map this inner Observable to the outer. Now you have your results in the outer Observable.
3. You can finally subscribe to this outer Observable again and take your response out. This should be the response from your service. Assign this value to your filteredOptions variable.

Finally, you need to remove the async pipe from your template as the subscribe block described above already does that for you:

```html
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar persona" aria-label="Search" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
                {{option}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**EDIT 1: Object Object being displayed**

Using the json pipe helps you understand what the response has in general. Once you've decided for one of the fields to display in your autocomplete, adjust your HTML:

```html
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar persona" aria-label="Search" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option.firstname">
                {{option.lastname}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I've set the [value] to the firstname of each option. But the display value inside the brackets is now set to lastname like {{ option.lastname }}. This means that you will see the lastname being displayed, but work with the firstname behind the scenes. You can of course set both to the same value if you need that.

Just one more tip: In your service you are calling the API and returning an Observable. Best case would be that you create an interface and use that to specify the type of the Observable. E.g.:

```js
export interface MyReturnType {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Here, use the fields that the json pipe displayed to use and create an interface out of that ;-)

Then you can do this:

```js
search(searchTerm: string): Observable<MyReturnType> {
    const url = this.PERSONA_URL;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('texto', searchTerm);

    return this.http.get(url, {params: params})
};
```

**EDIT 2: Search fires although the input is empty**

Because RxJS is just awesome, you can simply filter your valueChanges and define when it should trigger the service to make the HTTP call. Please find below example:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        filter(searchTerm => searchTerm.length >= 3),
        switchMap(searchTerm => this.personaService.search(searchTerm))
    ).subscribe(response => this.filteredOptions = response)
}
```

I've added the *filter()* operator in the pipe method. This filter checks if the searchTerm has a specific length (3 in this case) and only executes the next function (your switchMap) if this condition holds true.

By the way: The pipe() method allows to chain infinite number of operators from RxJS. You could do something like this to peek into your Observable:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        tap(searchTerm => console.log(searchTerm),
        filter(searchTerm => searchTerm.length >= 3),
        tap(searchTerm => console.log(searchTerm),
        switchMap(searchTerm => this.personaService.search(searchTerm))
    ).subscribe(response => this.filteredOptions = response)
}
```

Comment: It's working right now. Thanks a lot! But now I have a problem. I saw Object Object as a result and I used the json pipe. Now I see the entire json for each result and I want to see, for example, only the name and the surnames... How can I do that?

Comment: I've editted my answer to hopefully help you with that as well. If it helps, please accept the answer to make it visible for others too ;-)

Comment: It's working! I only made a change in your code. `public filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;` now is `public filteredOptions: PersonaDto;`. PersonaDto is my interface. Thanks a lot! I have another (last) question. It queries when nothing is written and shows me all the people (I have a LOT of people, more than 15k persons). Can I prevent that query to be executed  unless something is written?

Comment: I've extended my answer to cover this question, too ;-) Please accept the answer if it helps